# How can I display the data (column) from a database in a text in JavaFX, so that I get the next row from the column after clicking a button?

Tags: java, sql, javafx, derby

I am a newbie here. First of all I would like to apologize for my bad english. It's not my mother tongue. I haven't used the language for a long time.

I have a problem with my code. I want to display the first row of the column of my database in a text and when I click a button I want that I then get the second row of the column of my database. And so it should go on until I have no more rows to display in that particular column.

So far I've managed to show a row from the database in a "text", but the row is the last row from the database :)

This is the method in the Database class:

```
    public static String deutscheVokAn() {
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    String b = null;
    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connString);
        
        String str= "SELECT " + VocabelDeutsch + " FROM " + VocabelTable;
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(str);
        while (rs.next()) {
        b = rs.getString(VocabelDeutsch);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return b;
}
```

That is the scene in JavaFx and the text "txt" where it should be displayed:

```
Button zurueck = new Button("Zurück zum Hauptmenü");
    Label evl = new Label("Deutsch");
    Text txt = new Text();
    richtigfalsch = new Label();
    txtrichtig = new TextField("");
    txtrichtig.setPrefColumnCount(40);
    Button weiter = new Button("Weiter");
    
    HBox h1 = new HBox(10, txtrichtig, weiter);
    VBox v1 = new VBox(10, zurueck, evl, txt, richtigfalsch, h1);
    v1.setPadding(new Insets(5));
    Scene scene2 = new Scene(v1, 550, 300);
```

This is the implementation after you have clicked on the "weiter" (in English: Next) button:

```
weiter.setOnAction(e -> {
        primaryStage.show();
        txt.setText(Datenbank.deutscheVokAn());
        checkAnswer();
    
    });
```

I don't know if anyone would want to see the checkAnswer () method as well, but this is what it looks like:

```
    public void checkAnswer() {
    
        if (txtrichtig.getText().equals(Datenbank.englischeVokAn())) {
            richtigfalsch.setText("Richtig");
        } else {
            richtigfalsch.setText("Falsch");
        }
    
}
```

If someone wants to see the method englishVokAn() here:

```
    public static String englischeVokAn() {
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    String b = null;
    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connString);
        
        String str= "SELECT " + VocabelEnglisch + " FROM " + VocabelTable;          
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(str);
        while (rs.next()) {
        b = rs.getString(VocabelEnglisch);
        }
   
        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return b;
}
```

My database class:

```
public class Datenbank {

private static final String DBlocation = "C:\\Users\\musta\\Vokabeltrainer15_db";               
private static final String connString = "jdbc:derby:" + DBlocation + ";create=true";   
private static final String VocabelTable = "Vokabel";
private static final String VocabelID = "VokabelID";
private static final String VocabelDeutsch = "VokabelDeutsch";
private static final String VocabelEnglisch = "VokabelEnglisch";
```

The actual questions are:
Shouldn't I see the second row of the column when I click the Next button? (Apparently not: D)
How could I change my code so that I see the data (1st row, then after clicking the button "weiter" the second row) in this column "VocabelEnglisch" in the text "txt"?

Can someone help me?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: The loop where you call `while (rs.next())` is looping through all the rows, and overwriting the `String b` variable each time, so at the end of the loop, you have read all the rows, and `String b` has the value from the last row.

Comment: So then it makes sense, that I retrieve the last row of my column.

Comment: What if i want to store the data in an array list and then display each of that data.  How can I display an array list in JavaFX (except TableView)?